# run a command in post commit hook when commit a specific path

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server, post-commit-hook

I use VisualSVN Server and I want to trigger a build with Jenkins when a subfolder has been committed, but nothing happens.

My svn server link is: https://jenkins:8433/svn/TestServer/MyApplication/app

This is my code at post-commit:

```
svnlook dirs-changed %1 -r %2 | findstr /b /i "/TestServer/MyApplication/app"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    curl http://admin:11ca27ecadbb4a13589293ba29fe67d737@192.168.17.31:8080/job/Test/build?token=svntrigger
)
```